# Could not recieve information from environment production

Tags: puppet

Im getting this error on my node agent, when i run puppet agent --test

```
err: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment production source(s) puppet://puppet/plugins
```

The problem is that I don't have a environment called "production". Why is that being called? Is "production" some default or required name?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Could not retrieve information from environment production source(s) puppet://...**
>
> ```
> err: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve
> information from environment production source(s) puppet://foo/plugins
> ```

You are using pluginsync (good) however there are no plugin directories
on the puppet master - see this page 
http://projects.reductivelabs.com/issues/2244
Easiest solution is to ensure that you have at least one module with a "lib"
subdirectory.

source: http://bitcube.co.uk/content/puppet-errors-explained

Answer (score -1):

since i was not defining the environment when running puppet agent, it was calling production environment.

by specifying in /etc/puppet/puppet.conf

```
[agent]
environment NAME_OF_NODE
```

now it works

Comment: This is pretty horrible. Note that unless you messed around with `puppet.conf` on the master, `production` is the default environment, with the manifest in `/etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp` and modules in `/etc/puppet/modules`. How does your approach even work? Do you use directory environments? - I think the answer from TesselatingHeckler is closer to the mark.